# Splitting a byte[] into multiple byte[] arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to "chunk" up the bytes of an image. This will allow me to upload a large image in portions. I have the image currently stored as one large byte[]. I would like to split the byte array into `byte[]`'s with a maxlength of 512 elements. However, I'm not sure how to do this in the most efficient way.

Does anyone know how I can do this in the most efficient manner?

Comment: Hi chech this link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797/how-to-split-a-byte-array

I hope it helps,
bye

Comment: It seems fairly straightforward to come up with an O(N) solution (by iterating once through all of the bytes).  Are you looking for something better than O(N)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Array slices in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406485/array-slices-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765336/how-to-divide-array-of-file-paths-into-several-smaller-arrays/11765423#11765423

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient method would be: not to. If you already have the image as a single byte[] then for local code, just specifying the offset and length (perhaps som ArraySegment-of-byte) is usually sufficient. If your upload API only takes byte[], then you still shouldn't chunk it completely; just use a single 512 buffer and use Buffer.BlockCopy to load it will successive pieces of the data. You may need to resize (Array.Resize) the *final* chunk, but at most 2 arrays should be needed.

Even better; avoid needing a byte[] in the first place: consider loading the data via a streaming API (this will work well if the data is coming from a file); just use Read (in a loop, processing the returned value etc) to populate chunks of max 512. For example (untested, just of illustration):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
while(true) {
    int space = 512, read, offset = 0;
    while(space > 0 && (read = stream.Read(buffer, offset, space)) > 0) {
        space -= read;
        offset += read;
    }
    // either a full buffer, or EOF
    if(space != 0) { // EOF - final
       if(offset != 0) { // something to send
         Array.Resize(red buffer, offset);
         Upload(buffer);
       }
       break;
    } else { // full buffer
       Upload(buffer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I wrote an extension for this, originally for strings, but decided to make it generic.

```
    public static T[] CopySlice<T>(this T[] source, int index, int length, bool padToLength = false)
    {
        int n = length;
        T[] slice = null;

        if (source.Length < index + length)
        {
            n = source.Length - index;
            if (padToLength)
            {
                slice = new T[length];
            }
        }

        if(slice == null) slice = new T[n];
        Array.Copy(source, index, slice, 0, n);
        return slice;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T[]> Slices<T>(this T[] source, int count, bool padToLength = false)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < source.Length; i += count)
            yield return source.CopySlice(i, count, padToLength);
    }
```

Basically, you can use it like so:

```
byte[] myBytes; // original byte array

foreach(byte[] copySlice in myBytes.Slices(10))
{
    // do something with each slice
}
```

***Edit***:  I also provided an answer on SO using Buffer.BlockCopy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539638/how-to-efficiently-get-subset-of-byte-array-first-n-elements-in-c) but BlockCopy will only work on `byte[]` arrays, so a generic version for strings wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Not sure if the name is that well chosen. It's common that an array slice is referring to a part of the original array. (similar semantics to `ArraySegment<T>`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - I'm open to new names... Can you suggest one?

Comment: `CopySlice` would be pretty clear. Or `Subarray` analogous to `Substring`. Naming functions is so hard...

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Nice.  Thanks.  +1 for you :)

Comment: Wouldn't work for `byte[] myBytes = new byte[33];     foreach (byte[] copySlice in myBytes.Slices(16)) {....}`

Comment: @L.B - sorry... I went and grabbed my production version, it has added code to pad the final array, or not and works with odd numbers (left overs).

Answer (score 5):

```
public static IEnumerable<byte[]> Split(this byte[] value,int bufferLength){
   int countOfArray = value.Length / bufferLength;
   if(value.Length % bufferLength > 0)
      countOfArray ++;
   for(int i=0;i<countOfArray;i++)
   {
      yield return value.Skip(i * bufferLength).Take(bufferLength).ToArray();

   }
}
```

This is my extension what I used

Answer (score 3):

As of .NET 6, `System.Linq` has a built-in `Chunk` method for this.

For example:

```cs
using System.Linq;

...
  byte[] myBytes = new byte[131072];
  int myMaxChunkSizeInBytes = 512;
  foreach(byte[] chunk in myBytes.Chunk(myMaxChunkSizeInBytes))
  {
      // do something with each chunk
  }
...
```

MS Docs: [System.Linq.Enumerable.Chunk(IEnumerable, Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk)

Answer (score 2):

> I know this is old but needed the same solution and following works
>   perfectly for me hope this helps someone

```
private byte[][] ByteArrayToChunks(byte[] byteData, long BufferSize)
{
    byte[][] chunks = byteData.Select((value, index) => new { PairNum = Math.Floor(index / (double)BufferSize), value }).GroupBy(pair => pair.PairNum).Select(grp => grp.Select(g => g.value).ToArray()).ToArray();
    return chunks;
}
```

Comment: Looks really nice, but isn't really efficient. Nevertheless +1 for the alternative solution.