# Streaming jpegs via a web service

Tags: c#, wcf, image-processing, streaming, arrays

I am capturing jpegs from an IP camera. 
I upload it to my server via web service.
I then render the image to a canvas.
A User can then view the motion via a browser.

I had been using 4 ip cameras at a resolution of 360x288 each channel. The byte array size is typically 15kb.

Switching to the single ip camera with a resolution of 720x576 increaes the payload of the byte array to 4 times the single camera of 360x288.

I had noticed this question and answer here:

[Splitting a byte[] into multiple byte[] arrays in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816295/splitting-a-byte-into-multiple-byte-arrays-in-c-sharp)

The person who gave the ticked answer suggests do not use a byte array at all.  Just stream it.  Currently, I am using WCF TCP binding and I was wondering how could I implement this streaming option in this setup?

How would I use this for consecutive images (as opposed to a single video file)?

What would the code look like?  I am googling as I type but would it not be better to split the large byte array into 2 smaller ones and upload seperalty and then recombine on the server?

I am using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the streaming approach as it is much simpler than going through all of the work in reconstructing the image file on the server side.

**NetTcpBinding** supports the **TransferMode** of Streamed. The main limitation is that you cannot use the **SecurityMode** of Message.

You would configure it as such:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="PhotoUploadService">
                <endpoint name="" binding="netTcpBinding"
                    address="net.tcp://localhost:8000"
                    contract="IPhotoUploadService"
                    bindingConfiguration="streamedTcpBinding" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="streamedTcpBinding" 
                  transferMode="Streamed" 
                  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                  maxBufferSize="65536" />
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```